# SwifUI Navigation title broken when grouped in ZStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]I'm trying to add a background image behind the List - it looks right, but when I scroll the navigation title doesn't move. It works if I remove the ZStack and Image. How can I achieve both?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Image("GradientBackground")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            List {
                ...

        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: logoutButton)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Profile").font(.subheadline), displayMode: .automatic)
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

If I remove the ZStack and Image, it works when I scroll:
[image]

Comment: I ran the same code, I don't see any broken navigation title, can you share some pic or video what's actually broken ?

Comment: It looks like Xcode 12 / iOS 14 ignores such constructions at all - image, in this case, is not visible at all, ever.

Comment: Added example images

Comment: @Asperi oh really? I've been building on iOS 13 / Xcode 11